# How to move from model space to orthographic view in OpenGL 3.0+?

Tags: opengl, matrix, orthographic

I've recently completed some examples in OpenGL which resulted in me drawing some triangles in the space `-1 >= x <= 1`, `-1 >= y <= 1`. What do I need to do to move to an orthographic view? What transforms do I need to perform? I'm assuming the resulting transform will be set into the vertex shader as a uniform variable, then applied to any incoming vertices.

Is it wise to use pixels as the scale of the view (i.e. 1024x768) or to use logical units (pixels x1000 for example)?

Answer (score 3):

> What do I need to do to move to an orthographic view? What transforms do I need to perform?

You must apply a orthographic projection. Note that the identity transform you used so far is already orthographic.

It's a good idea to decompose the transformation process into projection and modelview transformations. Each is described by a 4×4 matrix, which, you a right, are passed as uniforms to the vertex shader.

The typical vertex shader layout looks like

```
#version 120 /* or something later */

attribute vec4 position;

uniform mat4 proj;
uniform mat4 mv;

varying vec4 vert_pos; // for later versions of GLSL replace 'varying' with 'out'

void main()
{
    // order matters, matrix multiplication is not 
    vert_pos = proj * mv * position; commutative */
}
```

The projection matrix itself must be supplied by you. You can either look at older fixed function OpenGL specifications to see how they're implemented. Or you use some ready to use graphics math library, like [→GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/) or (self advertisement) [→linmath.h](https://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h)

#### Update due to comment

The *modelview* transform is used to set the point of view and the placement of geometry drawn into the scene. In general the modelview usually differs for each model drawn. Modelview itself can be decomposed into model and view. The view is what some people set using some sort of "lookAt" function. And model is the geometry placement part.

The projection is kind of the "lens" of OpenGL and what's responsible for the "ortho" or "perspective" or whatever look.

*Like stated above the specific projection to be used is user defined, but usually follows the typical transformation matrices like found in older OpenGL specifications or in graphics math libraries.* Just look at some older specification of OpenGL (say OpenGL-1.5 or so) for the definition of *ortho* and *frustum* matrices (they can be found for the fixed functions glOrtho and glFrustum).

Comment: Thanks, what would the orthographic transform look like? Can you elaborate on the model-view transform?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, finally, what about using logical coordinates in the view space, vs using the actual pixel width and height of the window?

Comment: @MarkIngram: It all boils down to a coordinate transformation process. You start with whatever abstract vectors you like to. The only constraints put upon you by OpenGL is, that the end result must be in clip space, in the value range [-1, 1], and that OpenGL *will* apply the homogenous divide step afterwards. The value ranges [-1, 1] will be then mapped into the viewport extents. Everything else is up to you, i.e. you can apply transformation in whatever why you desire; the only limit is your imagination.

Comment: @MarkIngram: In the case of ortho projection mapping to viewport pixels, well: `ortho(left=0, right=viewport_width, bottom=0, top=viewport_height, z_limit_near, z_limit_far)`

Comment: +1 for linmath.h; it's really hard to find a "to the point" opengl math library which is C compatible as well as released under a very flexible license.